# Microsoft Azure LUIS API: Missing phraselist features field

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am using the API for Microsoft LUIS.  I downloaded the a model as a json file via their web interface and then uploaded it via the web interface with no problem.  I then wrote some code to upload the json file via their API and I am getting a 400: Bad Argument with this:  Missing phraselist features field.

Here is the code

```
open System.IO
let baseModelPath = @"C:\Resources\Model.2.json"
let text = File.ReadAllText(baseModelPath)

#r "System.Net.Http"
open System.Net.Http
open System.Text

let versionId = "0.3"
let uri = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/XXXXXX/versions/import?versionId=" + versionId
let subscriptionKey = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
let client = new HttpClient()
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey)
let content = new StringContent(text, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
let response = client.PostAsync(uri,content).Result
let resultJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
resultJson
```

Has anyone seen this before?  The internet is not much help...

Comment: I've uploaded models via the API using PowerShell with no issue. Can you provide you model file (or at least the top level attributes) and I can compare against mine to see if something is different?

Comment: Do you ever download it via the api?

Comment: Yes, you can export application version via the programmatic API. I'm using v3.0, though. https://eastus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/luis-programmatic-apis-v3-0-preview/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c40

Comment: I don't think the V2 API has it - I figured it out going row by row....

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the model and how the V2 API handles duplicates.  I uploaded unique values for Intents without a problem.  When I uploaded Utterences ("example" endpoint), some of the utterances did not persist.  Turns out that if you pass in the same value for utterance text, even if it has a different intentName, the 1st intent loses that utterance reference and the second one gets it.  Therefore, when the entire model is loaded, some of the intents have 0 associated utterances.  Try to build the model - it fails